# Javascript Puzzle - One Liner

Tags: javascript, callback

Can you solve this without throwing an error? The answer is a one-liner. This is from a dead job posting, the answer was requested in the response. I thought it was a clever way to weed out respondents, but I can't seem to answer it without also getting an error.

The obvious solution:

```
f.moo(alert(f.foo));
```

But that throws  `TypeError: callback is undefined { message="callback is undefined",  more...}`

```
var f = (function(){
  return {
    foo : "bar",
    moo : function(callback){
      callback.call(this)
    }
  }
})();
//alert "bar" by foo
```

Comment: What's the puzzle?  Or, what does, "alert 'bar' by us" mean?

Comment: @Bonnie For starters, the code does miss a semi-colon...

Comment: Šime Vidas: Only Douglas Crockford and Chuck Norris will be mad at you

Comment: @Šime: The semi-colon will actually be provided by the interpreter, so this script will compile and run correctly.

Comment: @Harmen But in this case, it would improve code-readability...

Comment: @Šime Vidas While I too would prefer to see a semicolon there, I also wouldn't be too quick to respond to a job posting by criticizing the coding style of the person doing the hiring. Unless missing semicolons in JavaScript is sufficient reason not to apply for the position. (Or, of course, "what's wrong with this code" is the question being asked.)

Comment: @VoteyDisciple Maybe it was a trick-question and they were waiting for someone to criticize the missing semi-colon :D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to pass `f.moo` a function. You're calling `alert` and passing the result of `alert`( which is nothing) instead.

```
f.moo(function() { alert(this.foo); });
```

Comment: I suspect that should be `this`.

Comment: @SLaks — You commented as I made that edit. It indeed should be `this.foo` not `f.foo`.

Comment: Was too late with my answer, which was exactly the same :) +1

Answer (score 2):

Uhm...

```
alert(f.foo);
```

Or did you forget to mention some requirement?

Comment: I believe the commented line at the bottom ("alert 'bar' by us") is incomplete. It likely said something along the lines of "alert 'bar' by using f.moo" or something like that.

Comment: Probably.  But when asked questions like this, *especially* in an interview, I always argue semantics.  They should know better than to ask half-assed questions... :)

Comment: Maybe they were trying to weed out people who assume the more complex solution is desired, instead of the obvious and simple one that was requested. :o)

Comment: @patrick: Maybe. In those situations I like to provide all of the possible solutions I can think of. If they force me to pick one (as though I were taking a test) I would pick whichever one I think would create a good 10-minute argument about why I picked that one... which, of course, would be just to create the argument.